# Type.GetType for System.Net types fails

Tags: .net, reflection

I just came across this oddity when trying to instantiate a WebProxy instance through reflection :

```
    Dim proxyType As Type = GetType(System.Net.WebProxy)
    MsgBox(proxyType.FullName)

    Dim reflProxyType As Type = Type.GetType(proxyType.FullName)
    MsgBox(reflProxyType.FullName) ' Here, reflProxyType is null => NullReferenceException
```

Changing the first line to other System namespaces (ie. System.Text.StringBuilder or System.String) works fine.

```
    Dim systemType As Type = GetType(System.Text.StringBuilder)
    MsgBox(systemType.FullName)

    Dim reflSystemType As Type = Type.GetType(systemType.FullName)
    MsgBox(reflSystemType.FullName) ' Here, everything works fine
```

Is there any reason for this behavior ? Am I missing something ? Did MS set up some restrictions on System.dll ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for `Type.GetType (string)`

> Parameters
>
> typeName Type: System.String
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   AssemblyQualifiedName. **If the type is in the  currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll,** it is sufficient to supply the type
>   name  qualified by its namespace.

The [`WebProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx) class is in *System.dll*, not Mscorlib.dll. Therefore, you must either:

1. Provide the assembly-qualified name instead of just the fully-qualified name. (or)
2. Use the [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) method.

Comment: I hadn't tried with Assembly.GetType(), which works. But shouldn't Type.GetType("System.Net.WebProxy, System") work without having to specify the assembly version, culture and token ? I thought this was only required if you had multiple versions of the same assembly loaded ? Is this because the System namespace is provided by different assemblies ?

Comment: ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx states : "The minimum information required in an assembly name specification is the textual name (IDENTIFIER) of the assembly.". which leaves me wondering why in this case I have to include all the extra information ?

Comment: That page describes fully-qualified names, not assembly-qualified names.